# how to impliment servlets in iis

Tags: java

how can i run or impliment servlet programs in microsoft iis server

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is - you can't. You need a servlet container to manage the servlets. But Tomcat appears to have a connector with which you can link it to the IIS:
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Alternatively, you can take a look at this article. It is a bit strange, though.
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2000/jw-0616-iis.html